# File missing in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app which locates its database in what I believe is a fairly standard manner, viz:

```
+ (NSString *)dbPath
{
    NSArray *a =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,
                                            NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *dir = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    return [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self dbFile]];
}
```

Here dbFile is a function that just returns the name of the database file.

Recently users have complained that the app sometimes fails to find its database. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I have not been keeping abreast of the latest changes in iOS.

Comment: Anything you store in the `NSCachesDirectory` can get deleted by the system.

Comment: Never use the caches directory for anything that can't be replaced.

Comment: Thanks guys, see my own answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I remember.

An app store reviewer told me that I could not store the database in the directory that I originally intended to use, because its contents were downloaded from the internet. He was wrong of course, but I was having a lot of trouble with them at the time, so I just moved the database to the cache area as requested.

That is why is sometimes gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I also save db in caches in current project.Whenever user run the app,it finds db correctly.Mainly I use with FMDB.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName]; 

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory])
{  
    NSString *backupDbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DBName" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    NSLog(@"Test backuppath %@",backupDbPath);
    if (backupDbPath == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Database path is nil");
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL copiedBackupDb = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath toPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
        if (!copiedBackupDb) NSLog(@"Copying database failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem useful. If the DB is read-only, there is no need to copy it to the Caches folder. Just read it from the bundle. If the DB is writable, why would you store it in the Caches folder where it can be deleted and changes will be lost?